# Working with a weird array that looks like an Arel relation

Tags: ruby

I'm getting this array returned from an API in my Rails app:

```
[#<GoCardless::User created_at=Wed, 13 Jun 2012 10:41:35 +0000, email="bob@cat.com", first_name="bob", id="03hhsXP5AX", last_name="cat">]
```

How can I work with it? I'd like to get its ID, for instance, but whilst it looks like an arel relation, its class is an array, and it's baffling me.

Comment: It's an array containing a `GoCardless::User` object. You can use `array.first` to get to the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the first element of the array.

```
res = api.call # => [#<GoCardless::User created_at=Wed, 13 Jun 2012 10:41:35 +0000
res.first # => #<GoCardless::User created_at=Wed, 13 Jun 2012 10:41:35 +0000
res.first.id # => "03hhsXP5AX"
```